# Enable missing Proguard optimizations

Tags: java, optimization, configuration, proguard

The [optimization page](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage/optimizations) in the Proguard manual lists most of the optimizations.  I specified every optimization listed and the following four optimizations are not enabled.

```
Number of merged wrapper classes:              0   (disabled)
Number of desynchronized methods:              0   (disabled)
Number of object peephole optimizations:       0   (disabled)
Number of math peephole optimizations:         0   (disabled)
```

How do I explicitly enable these optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

[Optimizer.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/code/ci/default/tree/core/src/proguard/optimize/Optimizer.java) has all of the flags for the optimizations.  The ones missing from the web page are:

- class/merging/wrapper
- code/simplification/math
- code/simplification/object
- method/marking/synchronized